# Getting Error: conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex:

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform, adt

While running the project into eclipse (ADT) I am getting following error:

```
[2014-07-03 16:21:50 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/ParseAuthenticationProvider;
[2014-07-03 16:21:50 - SimpleNexus] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/ParseAuthenticationProvider;
```

I googled it but i am not getting specific solution. 
Any body knows about it then please help me

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old(ish) question but I couldn't find an answer myself and this is one of the top Google hits for *multiple dex files define parse.com*.

I was getting the same error because there were 2 instances of the parse.jar.
I had imported the Parse SDK jar, and then imported the ParseLoginUI module which included a parse.jar making 2 parse.jar files in the project.
To fix, I deleted the parse.jar from the libs folder of my app and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Do you suppose there's any way to dis-include the parse.jar from the login library, since it's less up-to-date? It's probably not significant, but the parse SDK is version 1.8.1, while the .jar file in the login library is 1.8.0

Comment: Cant check at the moment, but I don't think so.
In theory, you should be able to replace the version in the login library with the newer version? Let me know if you try it and it works.

Comment: So I've tested this and you need the parse.jar in the login library, otherwise you get errors in the ParseUI activities.
You can replace the jar in the ParseUI/libs folder with a more up to date one, but you'll need to update the reference to the new version.
In AndroidStudio you can just right-click the error in the activity and choose to update that way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I actually already did that, put the 1.8.1 version in the UI library, that way I don't have to lose the docs that were linked to v1.8.1.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries and remove all except "Android 4.4.2".
Click OK.

Then Go to Project » Clean » Clean projects selected below » select your project and click OK. This should work.